# jpos : cannot find control data "0x0D" when using isoMsg.getString(id) method

Tags: java, jpos

Some field value contains 0x0D specail character
The value from the hexdump:

```
4041000000000001D0534534534112342340000
```

But when I get the field value using isoMsg.getString(field_id), I got an equal sign instead of the 0x0D character

```
4041000000000001=0534534534112342340000
```

Is there any method to return the value as is without changing any control character data ?

Comment: Which datatype have you configured for the field? E.g. for BCD encoded fields, I assume that JPos may replace the invalid 'D' nibble with a replacement character like '='.

Answer (score 1):

jPOS converts the 'D' into '=' on BCD fields using [ISOUtil.bcd2str](https://github.com/jpos/jPOS/blob/master/jpos/src/main/java/org/jpos/iso/ISOUtil.java#L400) method.

This is useful to deal with track2 data.

You can easily replace it back.

Answer (score 0):

Something's not right.  You're looking at this:

```
4041000000000001D0534534534112342340000
```

This is 39 characters, or 19.5 bytes.  Is this your issue?

Comment: It just doesn't make sense to interpret that string as character codes because you have half a character in that string.  What about the fact that "D" is the only letter in that string?